# Grouping arrays by key/values

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
 $array = array(
        array(
            'id' => '1',
            'brand' =>  'Nike',
            'available' => '2016-01-16',
            'price' => '25'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '2',
            'brand' =>  'Nike',
            'available' => '2016-01-16',
            'price' => '20'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '3',
            'brand' =>  'Puma',
            'available' => '2016-01-16',
            'price' => '20'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '4',
            'brand' =>  'Adidas',
            'available' => '2016-01-16',
            'price' => '30'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '5',
            'brand' =>  'Adidas',
            'available' => '2016-01-15',
            'price' => '32'
        ),
    );
```

What I'm looking to get is something like the following:

```
    array(
        'brand' => 'Nike',
        'data' => array(
            array(
                '2016-01-16' => '25'
            ),
            array(
                '2016-01-16' => '20'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'brand' => 'Puma',
        'data' => array(
            array(
                '2016-01-16' => '20'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'brand' => 'Adidas',
        'data' => array(
            array(
                '2016-01-16' => '30'
            ),
            array(
                '2016-01-15' => '32'
            )
        )
    );
```

Whereby the array is grouped by brand and contains the `available` and `price` as subarrays.

Ideally I'd like to be able to loop though the array and get information like the following:

```
    $data['brand']; // will store the brand (Nike, Puma etc)
    $data['brand']['data']
```

Or something like this where I can easily loop thorough and extract the data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does the job:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $record) {
    if (!isset($result[$record['brand']])) {
        $result[$record['brand']] = array(
            'brand' => $record['brand'],
            'data' => array(array($record['available'] => $record['price'])),
        );
    }
    else {
        $result[$record['brand']]['data'][] = array($record['available'] => $record['price']);
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: That seems to work almost... The problem is, I'd liek to have the `data` elements in arrays, like `'data' => array(
            array(
                '2016-01-16' => '25'
            ),
            array(
                '2016-01-16' => '20'
            )
        )`

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much